# Php function to search through an array of objects using a string

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Am trying to come up with a code to search for  a string in an array     of   objects, if string is found, get values of the submenus object. Like if   the string "main/dashboard" is found then get submenus

```
stdClass Object
(
[type] => single
[slug] => view_admin_dashboard
[menus] => stdClass Object
    (
        [label] => Dashboard
        [icon] => dashboard
        [url] => main/dashboard
    )
[submenus] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [submenu_slug] => view_all_users
                [label] => View all Users
                [icon] => users
                [url] => main/users/all
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [submenu_slug] => delete_users
                [label] => Delete Users
                [icon] => users
                [url] => main/user/delete
            )
    )
)
```

I have this for now but its giving me error in_array expects parameter 2     to be array;

```
foreach($mainarray as $menus => $menu){
   if(in_array("main/dashboard",$menu)){
      foreach($menu as $submenu){
         echo $submenu->url;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `$mainarray`?

Comment: $main array is the whole array am using

Comment: That is not an array to begin with, but an object - that’s why it says `stdClass` in the debug output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
foreach($mainarray as $menu){
   if($menu->menus->url == "main/dashboard"){ // if found the url in the object
      foreach($menu->submenus as $submenu)
         echo $submenu->url;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the solution will not work in case if words are in upercase/lowercase both format.